# Tool vs. Application vs. Software

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, word-difference

I want to speak about an application in Windows which helps ESL students in listening and spelling.

> In this paper we present a tool that is aimed to improve the sound-to-letter skill of ESL students.

In the sentence above I want to emphasize that is a **computer** application, can I say computer tool? what is the best word

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your sentence, "software" or "software tool" would sound better than "computer tool".

I assume that this context is the introduction to an academic paper.  In this context, there are several possible meanings of "tool", including software, a paper-and-pencil evaluation tool, or even a mirror.  As Will points out, "computer tool" is not idiomatic.  Also, the phrase "aimed to" is not idiomatic.  The word "software" means "computer program(s)", and can include anything from small pieces of a program to collections of many programs.

In your professional jargon, is "sound-to-letter skill" a singular noun that includes the skill of converting all sounds to letters?  Or did you mean to use the plural "sound-to-letter skills", which treats transcriptions of different sounds as distinct skills?

I would change the sentence to something like one of these sentences:

> In this paper, we present software that is designed to improve the sound-to-letter skills of ESL students.
>
> In this paper, we present software that is intended to improve the sound-to-letter skills of ESL students.
>
> In this paper, we present software that is aimed at improving the sound-to-letter skills of ESL students.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however it is a draft and now I change it to "*In this paper we present software that is designed to enhance listening and spelling skills of ESL students. It achieves this goal by improving the auditory discrimination and sound-to-letter recognition skills of the students.*" Do you see some awkward constructions in it?

Comment: Your revised text is excellent.

Comment: How is correct to say "**software application**" then?

Comment: @SovereignSun -- You might want to ask a separate question about "software applications".  Depending on the context, the word "software" can help clarify the meaning, or it might be redundant.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your audience - if they have a little bit of IT knowledge, they will definitely know that you mean a kind of computer application (especially in context), instead of a hammer or screwdriver.

Adding the word 'computer' does not make it any clearer - a screwdriver could be a 'computer tool' as well because you need one to open it up. If you're unsure, use 'computer program': everybody will know what you mean by that.

Answer (score 2):

As a developer, I am constantly second guessing myself as to what to call certain kinds of programs.

I would call a language-teaching program a "tool".  Tool implies a certain usefulness that is not implied by "software" or "application."  Facebook or video games can be called software.  A teaching software can confidently be called "tool."  Note that while "computer software" is acceptable, "computer tool" sounds odd.

An opinion-based hierarchy for terms:

`Software` - does the most, could have dozens of uses (Like an operating system)

`Application` - Generally does one thing, sometimes more but generally related to the same task (clock that also is a timer and stopwatch.)

`Tool` - Is focused on one task (A web-browser or language-teaching tool)

These are just my opinions, hope it helps.